# Wordpress password protect certain parts of my site and create logins

Tags: wordpress, password-protection

I'm a newbie to Wordpress and I need to password protect certain pages of my site. I also need to be able to have users request a password that I can then create and send them so they can log in and see the content that is password protected. Any plugins or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Password protecting posts and pages is [actually built in to WordPress.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection)

On the left hand side of your page editor, you will see this:

[image: Wordpress Password Protect Example]

If you change the visibility from *public* to *password protected* you can ensure that only logged in users can see that specific page/post.

If you want to approve user registrations, I would suggest having a look at the [New User Approve plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/). Alternatively, you can try to write a function to do it yourself, and if you get stuck, post your progress here and we can help you adjust.

Comment: I do see that on the page editor but what if you want it to be a different password for each person, it's just asking for one password that I'm assuming everyone would have to use the same.

Comment: Nope. It's for each user. So any user who wants to see the post would have to log in with __their own login details__.